# Not getting Text with style on Dots in Multi Linechart in D3.js

Tags: angular, d3.js

[I created JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/z9uoywjq/42/)

I found many examples to display text on dot on line chart. But I couldn't able to figure out in my application.

**I added svg.append("text") and d3.select(this) to display text and style on dot. Text is displaying but not able to add style for text.**

```js
var data = [{
  depotID: 123,
  depotName: "All Depots",
  materials: [{
      materialName: "M7824 (MSB0011359C) 600 mg",
      materialTypeID: 1234,
      materialStock: [{
          date: "2020-10-01",
          stock: 100
        },
        {
          date: "2020-11-01",
          stock: 200
        },
        {
          date: "2020-12-01",
          stock: 300
        },
        {
          date: "2021-01-01",
          stock: 400
        },
        {
          date: "2021-02-01",
          stock: 500
        },
        {
          date: "2021-03-01",
          stock: 600
        },
        {
          date: "2021-04-01",
          stock: 700
        },
        {
          date: "2021-05-01",
          stock: 800
        },
        {
          date: "2021-06-01",
          stock: 900
        },
        {
          date: "2021-07-01",
          stock: 1000
        },
        {
          date: "2021-08-01",
          stock: 1100
        },
        {
          date: "2021-09-01",
          stock: 1200
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      materialName: "M7824 (MSB0011359C) 500 mg",
      materialID: 1232,
      materialStock: [{
          date: "2020-10-01",
          stock: 200
        },
        {
          date: "2020-11-01",
          stock: 300
        },
        {
          date: "2020-12-01",
          stock: 400
        },
        {
          date: "2021-01-01",
          stock: 500
        },
        {
          date: "2021-02-01",
          stock: 560
        },
        {
          date: "2021-03-01",
          stock: 870
        },
        {
          date: "2021-04-01",
          stock: 800
        },
        {
          date: "2021-05-01",
          stock: 900
        },
        {
          date: "2021-06-01",
          stock: 1000
        },
        {
          date: "2021-07-01",
          stock: 1100
        },
        {
          date: "2021-08-01",
          stock: 1200
        },
        {
          date: "2021-09-01",
          stock: 1300
        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}]
let width = 900,
  height = 400,
  margin = 100;


var dates = [];
for (let obj of data[0].materials[0].materialStock) {
  dates.push(obj.date);
}

var domain = d3.extent(dates);
var newStartDate = new Date(domain[0]).setDate(new Date(domain[0]).getDate() - 15);
var newEndtDate = new Date(domain[1]).setDate(new Date(domain[1]).getDate() + 15);

var xScaleTest = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date(newStartDate), new Date(newEndtDate)])
  .range([0, width - margin * 2]);

var yScaleTest = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].materials, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.materialStock, function(d) {
      return d.stock;
    })
  })])
  .range([height - margin, 0]);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#xyAxes").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width + margin) + "px")
  .attr("height", (height + margin) + "px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

//Add Line
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScaleTest(new Date(d.date))
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock)
  });

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

var groups = lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data[0].materials).enter()
  .append('g');

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal((d3.schemeCategory10));
//d3.scaleOrdinal().range(seriesColors);// (d3.schemeCategory10);

//line
groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.materialStock)
  })
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5") //dashed array for line;

//dot on line
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data[0].materials)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.materialStock;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScaleTest((new Date(d.date)));
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock);
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d);

    d3.select(this)
      .attr("class", 'tooltip').style("font-size", "15px")
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0.1)
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("text-align", "center")
      .style("width", " 60px")
      .style("height", "28px")
      .style("background", "lightsteelblue")
      .style("border", "3px")
      .style("border-radius", "8px");

    svg.append("text")
      .text(d.stock)
      .attr("id", "t" + d.x + "-" + d.y + "-" + d.materialName)
      .attr("x", xScaleTest(new Date(d.date)))
      .attr("y", yScaleTest(d.stock))
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {

    d3.select("#t" + d.x + "-" + d.y + "-" + d.materialName).remove();
    d3.select(this)
      .style("cursor", "none")
      .transition()
      .style("opdacity", 0)
      .duration(500)
      .attr("fill", "none");
    //.select("text").remove();
  })

// Add title      
svg.append("svg:text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", -50)
  .attr("y", -100)
  .text("Material Stock Forecast")
  .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("color", "#353535")

/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScaleTest)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%Y"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScaleTest).ticks(12);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

path.domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ed3700;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

text.title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="xyAxes"></div>
```

**Current Behavior** [image]

**Expected result is**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add zoom and tooltip on the same line chart in d3js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879042/is-it-possible-to-add-zoom-and-tooltip-on-the-same-line-chart-in-d3js)

Comment: I tried to create div tag and append to SVG element. but Text is not displaying and its coming only in Console.log

Comment: Believe me I couldn't able to figure out. I appreciate if you can update my Fiddle or suggest me @ Ruben Helsloot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```js
var data = [{
  depotID: 123,
  depotName: "All Depots",
  materials: [{
      materialName: "M7824 (MSB0011359C) 600 mg",
      materialTypeID: 1234,
      materialStock: [{
          date: "2020-10-01",
          stock: 100
        },
        {
          date: "2020-11-01",
          stock: 200
        },
        {
          date: "2020-12-01",
          stock: 300
        },
        {
          date: "2021-01-01",
          stock: 400
        },
        {
          date: "2021-02-01",
          stock: 500
        },
        {
          date: "2021-03-01",
          stock: 600
        },
        {
          date: "2021-04-01",
          stock: 700
        },
        {
          date: "2021-05-01",
          stock: 800
        },
        {
          date: "2021-06-01",
          stock: 900
        },
        {
          date: "2021-07-01",
          stock: 1000
        },
        {
          date: "2021-08-01",
          stock: 1100
        },
        {
          date: "2021-09-01",
          stock: 1200
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      materialName: "M7824 (MSB0011359C) 500 mg",
      materialID: 1232,
      materialStock: [{
          date: "2020-10-01",
          stock: 200
        },
        {
          date: "2020-11-01",
          stock: 300
        },
        {
          date: "2020-12-01",
          stock: 400
        },
        {
          date: "2021-01-01",
          stock: 500
        },
        {
          date: "2021-02-01",
          stock: 560
        },
        {
          date: "2021-03-01",
          stock: 870
        },
        {
          date: "2021-04-01",
          stock: 800
        },
        {
          date: "2021-05-01",
          stock: 900
        },
        {
          date: "2021-06-01",
          stock: 1000
        },
        {
          date: "2021-07-01",
          stock: 1100
        },
        {
          date: "2021-08-01",
          stock: 1200
        },
        {
          date: "2021-09-01",
          stock: 1300
        },

      ]
    }
  ]
}]
let width = 900,
  height = 400,
  margin = 100;


var dates = [];
for (let obj of data[0].materials[0].materialStock) {
  dates.push(obj.date);
}

var domain = d3.extent(dates);
var newStartDate = new Date(domain[0]).setDate(new Date(domain[0]).getDate() - 15);
var newEndtDate = new Date(domain[1]).setDate(new Date(domain[1]).getDate() + 15);

var xScaleTest = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date(newStartDate), new Date(newEndtDate)])
  .range([0, width - margin * 2]);

var yScaleTest = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].materials, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.materialStock, function(d) {
      return d.stock;
    })
  })])
  .range([height - margin, 0]);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#xyAxes").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width + margin) + "px")
  .attr("height", (height + margin) + "px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

var tooltip = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
  .attr('id', 'tooltip')
  .style("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "px," + margin.top + "px)")
  .classed('hide', true);

//Add Line
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScaleTest(new Date(d.date))
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock)
  });

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

var groups = lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data[0].materials).enter()
  .append('g');

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal((d3.schemeCategory10));
//d3.scaleOrdinal().range(seriesColors);// (d3.schemeCategory10);

//line
groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.materialStock)
  })
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5") //dashed array for line;

//dot on line
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data[0].materials)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.materialStock;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScaleTest((new Date(d.date)));
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock);
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
    // Show the tooltip and position it correctly
    var x = xScaleTest(new Date(d.date)) + margin;
    var y = yScaleTest(d.stock) + margin;
    tooltip.classed('hide', false)
      .style('left', x.toString() + 'px')
      .style('top', y.toString() + 'px')
      .text(d.stock);
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    tooltip.classed('hide', true);
  });

// Add title      
svg.append("svg:text")
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", -50)
  .attr("y", -100)
  .text("Material Stock Forecast")
  .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .style("color", "#353535")

/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScaleTest)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%Y"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScaleTest).ticks(12);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

path.domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ed3700;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

text.title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #353535;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin: 20px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="xyAxes"></div>
```

Comment: Somehow I couldn't able to write css into file. I have to write inline tooltip css for style in to mouseenter event.
Thanks you @Ruben Helsloot

Comment: In that case, write it where you create the tooltip: `var tooltip = d3.select('body')`

Comment: Finally done with css. I added css in where create tooltip. Thank you @Ruben Helsloot

Comment: @@Ruben, Here i want to fill same line color in to  dot when mouse oven and remove  when mouse out.
(mouseenter)
 d3.select(this).style("fill",(d, i) => colors(i));
(mouseout)
 d3.select(this).style("fill","none");
But its picking different color not same color
Here is my Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/z9uoywjq/75/